# Bind Checkboxlist using Tag Helper

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to bind checkboxlist using tag helper. The problem is my checkboxlist always return false. It works if I use request.form["Category"] not tag helper. Where my problem is here. Thanks.

Model:

```
public partial class Policy 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public List<PolicyCategory> Categories { get; set; }    
}
public class PolicyCategory
{
    [Key]
    public int Category_id { get; set; }
    public string Category_name { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public bool Selected { get; set; }

}
```

Controller:

```
     [HttpPost]
            [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
            public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Category")] Policy policy)
            {
                    var checkedString = string.Empty;
                    List<PolicyCategory> Categories = PopulateCategories();
                    for (int i = 0; i < Categories.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        if (Categories[i].Selected==true)
                        {
                            checkedString += Categories[i].Category_name + ",";
                        }
                    }
                    ...
                return View(policy);
            }
```

View:

```
   

    for (int i=0; i<Model.Categories.Count(); i++)
            {
                <input  type="checkbox" asp-for="@Model.Categories[i].Selected" />
                <label asp- 
              for="@Model.Categories[i].Selected">@Model.Categories[i].Category_name</label>
                <input  type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Categories[i].Category_id" />
                <input  type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Categories[i].Category_name" />
                <br />
                }
            }
```

Comment: `It works if I use request.form["Category"] not tag helper.` Are your sure you can get the value by request.form?   Your razor code does not contain any elements named `Category`. Only if you set the element named `Category`, the backend can receive the value. If you are sure you can get by request.form, I think you need share your html design for `Category`. From your shared razor code, it uses the correct way to bind value to `Categories` property, but you need remember remove `[Bind("Category")]` or use `[Bind("Category,Categories")]`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't say it clearly. I use <input type="checkbox" name="Category" /> when I use the request.form["Category"] . The tag helper doesn't need to specify the name="Category"

Comment: I tried to remove  [Bind("Category")] and use [Bind("Category, Categories")], it doesn't work. The code doesn't run the for loop in the controller.

Comment: It is impossible to bind multiple checkbox value to just string type Category. use `[Bind("Category, Categories")]` and `<input  type="checkbox" asp-for="@Model.Categories[i].Selected" />` can bind value to Categories. If it cannot bind to Categories, you may consider if you share the correct current code to us. If you want to bind multiple checkbox with `<input type="checkbox" name="Category" />`, you need change `string Category` to `List<string> Category`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I changed to  public string List<PolicyCategory> Category { get; set; }  in the model class, and bind both [Bind("Category, Categories")], and it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Model:
    public partial class Policy 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<PolicyCategory> Category { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public List<PolicyCategory> Categories { get; set; }    
}

View:

    for (int i=0; i<Model.Categories.Count(); i++)
            {
                <input  type="checkbox" asp-for="@Model.Categories[i].Selected" />
                <label asp-for="@Model.Categories[i].Selected">@Model.Categories[i].Category_name</label>
                <input  type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Categories[i].Category_id" />
                <input  type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Categories[i].Category_name" />
                <br />
                }
            }
```